# Can't generate Javascript from data with parentheses

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using a PHP/MySQL connection to add a search suggestions feature to my site. It's all working except for one piece. My data all contains parentheses in the values, so when I'm trying to pass the returned data to the input field my onclick function fails! code is as follows:

```
while ($result = $query->fetch_object()) {
            echo '</li><li onclick="fill(\''.$result->name.'\');">'.$result->name.'</li>';
        }
```

The list populates from the returned search results, but the query returned looks like this:

```
</li><li onclick="fill('Boire Field&#44; Nashua&#44; NH&#44; US (KASH)');">
Boire Field&#44; Nashua&#44; NH&#44; US (KASH)</li>
```

Firebug gives me the following:

```
unterminated string literal
    fill('Boire Field, Nashua, NH, US (KASH)
```

The `)` in the result is prematurely ending the string. How can I escape this out so it will properly call the function?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-including-escaping-newlines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Brad Suggests.. The best way is [JSON_ENCODE](https://www.php.net/json_encode)

```
while ($result = $query->fetch_object()) {
            echo '</li><li onclick="fill(\''.json_encode($result->name).'\');">'.$result->name.'</li>';
        }
```

Comment: I added `json_encode` like your example, but this is all it returns: `onclick="fill('"Boire Field&#44; Nashua&#44; NH&#44; US (KASH)\r"')`. It looks like it added a `\r` but left the parentheses, which still kicks back "unterminated string literal".

Comment: Aha! I used URLENCODE and it worked! Thanks for the kick in the right direction!

Comment: What exactly is your value in the "$result->name", is it "Boire Field, Nashua, NH, US (KASH)", if yes, then json_encode should just return `"Boire Field, Nashua, NH, US (KASH)"`

Comment: Oh, Okay. You are welcome. I was about to write more example for it :)

Comment: By the way for other people reading this it ended up also being a problem with trailing carriage returns (hence the `\r`) in the data set. A simple `trim()` took care of that one.